# How to iterate through list of dictionaries and sort the output based on the key in Bash?

Tags: bash, ubuntu

We are getting the output from an API call in the below list of dictionaries format,

```
[
{
        "Key": "/builder-deployer/test2/services/serviceA/ip",
        "Val": "10.1.2.1"
    },
    {
        "Key": "/builder-deployer/test2/services/serviceA/port",
        "Val": "2"
    },
    {
        "Key": "/builder-deployer/test2/services/serviceA/url",
        "Val": "serviceA.abc.com"
    },
    {
        "Key": "/builder-deployer/test2/services/serviceA/username",
        "Val": "jenkins"
    },
    {
        "Key": "/builder-deployer/test2/services/serviceB/ip",
        "Val": "10.1.2.2"
    },
    {
        "Key": "/builder-deployer/test2/services/serviceB/port",
        "Val": "3"
    },
    {
        "Key": "/builder-deployer/test2/services/serviceB/url",
        "Val": "serviceB.abc.com"
    },
    {
        "Key": "/builder-deployer/test2/services/serviceB/username",
        "Val": "jenkins"
    },
    {
        "Key": "/builder-deployer/test2/services/serviceC/ip",
        "Val": "10.1.2.2"
    },
    {
        "Key": "/builder-deployer/test2/services/serviceC/port",
        "Val": "4"
    },
    {
        "Key": "/builder-deployer/test2/services/serviceC/url",
        "Val": "serviceC.abc.com"
    },
    {
        "Key": "/builder-deployer/test2/services/serviceC/username",
        "Val": "jenkins"
    }
]
```

I have a requirement to fetch the unique username and IP combination in the form of username@ip from the list to install some dependencies.
i.e. in the above list of dictionaries, we have 2 unique username@ip combinations. So I need to install packages on **jenkins@10.1.2.1**, **jenkins@10.1.2.2** machines respectively.

I have the below code in a python script that does the same but most of our code is in Bash, we want to convert this also to Bash. Any help would be very helpful

```
ip=[]
for username in outputs:
    for ip in outputs:
        if username['Key'].split('/')[-2] == ip['Key'].split('/')[-2] and username['Key'].split('/')[-1] in ['username'] and ip['Key'].split('/')[-1] in ['ip']:
            ip.append(username['Val']+'@'+ip['Val'])
print(set(ip))
```

Comment: I'd leave it in python. bash has no native JSON capability, and its idea of a dictionary is limited and hard to work with for what you're doing. Basically, from a bash script, you'd have to pull in an external tool like `jq` or `python` or something like that that understood JSON, and once you've done that you might as well have that tool do the whole job.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**jq**

```
$ FILE="file.json"
$ paste -d@ \
        <(jq -r '.[]|select(.Key|contains("/username")).Val' "$FILE") \
        <(jq -r '.[]|select(.Key|contains("/ip")).Val' "$FILE") | \
        sort -u

jenkins@10.1.2.1
jenkins@10.1.2.2
```

**awk**

```
awk -F\" '/\/ip/{getline;ip=$4}/username/{getline;$0=$4"@"ip;print|"sort -u"}' "$FILE"

jenkins@10.1.2.1
jenkins@10.1.2.2
```

Answer (score 1):

The suggestion in the comments to leave your solution in python (per Gordon Davisson) would be my preference as well.   But, if you really have to have a bash solution, the following is one option.  Bear in mind it will be fragile if your API JSON format changes over time.  It is also not terribly efficient as it relies on reading the source JSON multiple occasions.  Further, both `grep` and `sort` are also utilized:

```
#!/bin/bash

input_json="${1:-/tmp/bar/t.json}"

while read -r line ; do
    search_str=$(grep -oB 1 "${line}" "${input_json}" \
     | awk 'NR==1 {gsub(/^"/,"", $2); \
     gsub(/ip",$/,"username", $2); print $2}')
    
    user=$(grep -oA 1 "${search_str}" "${input_json}" | \
     awk 'NR==2 {gsub(/"/,"", $2); print $2}')
    
    echo "${user}@${line}"

# get unique ip addresses from source json
done < <(grep -Eo "([0-9]{1,3}[\.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}" "${input_json}" | sort -u)
```

Sample data:

```
[
{
        "Key": "/builder-deployer/test2/services/serviceA/ip",
        "Val": "10.1.2.1"
    },
    {
        "Key": "/builder-deployer/test2/services/serviceA/port",
        "Val": "2"
    },
    {
        "Key": "/builder-deployer/test2/services/serviceA/url",
        "Val": "serviceA.abc.com"
    },
    {
        "Key": "/builder-deployer/test2/services/serviceA/username",
        "Val": "jenkins"
    },
    {
        "Key": "/builder-deployer/test2/services/serviceB/ip",
        "Val": "10.1.2.2"
    },
    {
        "Key": "/builder-deployer/test2/services/serviceB/port",
        "Val": "3"
    },
    {
        "Key": "/builder-deployer/test2/services/serviceB/url",
        "Val": "serviceB.abc.com"
    },
    {
        "Key": "/builder-deployer/test2/services/serviceB/username",
        "Val": "jenkins"
    },
    {
        "Key": "/builder-deployer/test2/services/serviceC/ip",
        "Val": "10.1.2.2"
    },
    {
        "Key": "/builder-deployer/test2/services/serviceC/port",
        "Val": "4"
    },
    {
        "Key": "/builder-deployer/test2/services/serviceC/url",
        "Val": "serviceC.abc.com"
    },
    {
        "Key": "/builder-deployer/test2/services/serviceC/username",
        "Val": "jenkins"
    }
]
```

Sample output:

```
$ ./t.sh
jenkins@10.1.2.1
jenkins@10.1.2.2
```

Answer (score 1):

Use jq once, no need of temporary file

```
$ cat test.json | jq -r '.[]|select(.Key|test("(username|ip)$")).Val' \
  | paste -d '@' - - | sort -u
10.1.2.1@jenkins
10.1.2.2@jenkins
```